# what is the formal notation about the CDF or PDF of a function with limited interval.

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Given an arbitrary function, like $d(t)$, within some finite interval $[t_1,t_2]$, we can get its PDF and CDF by sampling, as shown like
[image: Converce from a function to its CDF and PDF]

My question is where there is any formal notation to describe them. The reason why I do not call them CDF and PDF is because $d(t)$ is deterministic.

My final aim is to use some formal notation to describe the following question
$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_2}g\left(d\left(t\right)\right)\cdot \mathbb{I}\left\{b(t)<\bar{B}\right\} \ dt=(t_2-t_1)\int_{0}^{\bar{B}}g\left(u\right)\ dF_{d(t)}(u)
$$
where $F_{d(t)}(u)$ is the CDF of $d(t)$ within $[t_1,t_2]$.

Comment: Try this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_measure

Comment: Thx for your comments. The empirical measure can be used to describe the process I get CDF and PDF by sampling. But the empirical measure essentially is used for the iid random variables, which is not suitable for this case, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plots approximate the CDF and PDF of the r.v. $Y=d(T),$ where r.v. $T\sim\text{Uniform}[t_1,t_2].$ Your equation should therefore be $$\begin{align}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}g\left(d\left(t\right)\right)\cdot \mathbb{I}\left\{b(t)<\bar{B}\right\} \ dt
&=(t_2-t_1)\,\mathbb{E}\left[g\left(d\left(T\right)\right)\cdot \mathbb{I}\left\{b(T)<\bar{B}\right\} \right]\\ 
&=(t_2-t_1)\,\mathbb{E}\left[g\left(Y\right)\cdot \mathbb{I}\left\{Y\in C\right\} \right]\\
&=(t_2-t_1)\int_{C}g\left(y\right)\ dF_{Y}(y)\end{align}$$
where $C=\{d(t):\ b(t)<\bar B,\ t\in[t_1,t_2] \}.$ The set $C$ is determined by both functions $d(.)$ and $b(.),$ and might not be $[0,\bar B]$ as you've written.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Your explanation is clear and using the uniform distribution to construct the r.v. $Y$ is so genius. But I am not sure the first equal sign is always true, that is,
$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}g\left(d\left(t\right)\right)\cdot \mathbb{I}\left\{b(t)<\bar{B}\right\} \ dt
=(t_2-t_1)\,\mathbb{E}\left[g\left(d\left(T\right)\right)\cdot \mathbb{I}\left\{b(T)<\bar{B}\right\} \right]$$
since the left side is a integral and the right side is a expectation. Is it from some basic theorem.

Comment: @LeeWhite It's from the definition of expectation, note that pdf of $T$ is $1/(t_{2}-t_{1})$ on $[t_{1},t_{2}]$, so $\mathbb{E}[h(T)]\equiv\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}h(t)/(t_{2}-t_{1})dt$, that is $\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}h(t)dt=(t_{2}-t_{1})\mathbb{E}[h(T)]$.

Comment: That's so great. Thank you.